# How to organise CakePHP2 page specific js and css ibraries

Tags: cakephp

I'm looking for a way to organise my js and css libraries in CakePHP 2.4.1, but I cannot seem to find the best way to do it.

In my layout.ctp is a  section where all js and css libraries are included. However all libraries are loaded on every page while only some should be loaded per page.

I could define the required libraries in the corresponding controller, but I don't think this is a good MVC practice.

Hope to hear some good advice.

Comment: Have you looked into [view blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load scripts and css on demand directly in the view file.

That way, you will only load in your layout the scripts and/or css needed for your view.

As described here in the documentation : [using blocks for scripts and css files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files)

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but it's not usually the best solution. Minifying everything for all pages into one file is usually more efficient.

Comment: @joshua.paling The amount of JS and CSS is huge in our case, and really differs on page level. Because of this I wouldn't like to combine all CSS and JS for use on all pages.

I have solved the problem by defining a block in the layout, and filling it with the right CSS and JS from within the view file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much js / css you have. If it's not a huge amount, you should concatenate / minify all your js / css into a single file, and just include that on every page. I use [Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) for this. Mark Story's [asset compress plugin](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress) is apparently also good, though I haven't used it.

Minified JS / CSS is pretty small.